# Wrong behavior of Ctrl+Left/Right in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, keymaps

In  IntelliJ IDEA **File->Settings->Keymap->Editor**, actions I have for

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd><</kbd>/<kbd>></kbd> is  -> **Move caret to prev/next word**.

However when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>></kbd> key it starts moving with word selection. What could be the problem here?

Very uncomfortable to work! I'm under Linux Mint 18 (Ubuntu 16.04) now.

Comment: What operation system do you use?

Comment: @maxteneff, Linux Mint (Ubuntu)

Comment: Are you sure you are not pressing 'Shift' or no problem with keyboard? what is the keymap style you are using?

Comment: Have you made sure that "Move caret to prev/next word _with selection_" doesn't have the same keys mapped?

Comment: @SupunWijerathne, seems no problem with keyboard - works fine in other editors. Reproducible in with few styles: KDE, Netbeans, etc.

Comment: @walen, no keys are different: Ctrl-Shift-Right/Left

Answer (score 0):

In File->Settings->Editor->General->Smart Keys need to uncheck "Add multiple carets on double Ctrl with arrow keys"